# ASP.NET CreateTextFile 99.9% free of errors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a routine "BlahStat.aspx" running on an Azure website that is called by a remote service (not controlled by us) and writes a file containing status information to the local directory.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" explicit="true" validateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Import namespace="ADODB" %>
<%@ Import namespace="WinHttp" %>
<%@ Import namespace="MSXML" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Scripting" %>

<script language="VB" runat="Server">

Function CreateRandomGUID(ByRef tmpLength As Integer) As String
    Randomize(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Timer())
    Dim tmpCounter As Integer
    Dim tmpGUID As String
    Const strValid As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    For tmpCounter = 1 To tmpLength
        tmpGUID = tmpGUID & Mid(strValid, Int(Rnd(1) * Len(strValid)) + 1, 1)
    Next 
    tmpGUID = tmpGUID & Right(New String(Chr(48), 5) & CStr(Int(Rnd(1) * 100000)), 5)
    CreateRandomGUID = tmpGUID
End Function

Dim MsgFilePath As String = "D:\home\site\mailroot\Drop"
Dim strstatus As String
Dim strid As String
Dim strMessageName As String
Dim dtCurrentDate As Date
Dim RecAddr As String
Dim SendAddr As String
Dim FileObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim OutputString As String
Dim MsgFile As Scripting.IFile
Dim strTempFile As String
Dim OutStream As Scripting.ITextStream
</script>

<%
strid = request.QueryString.Item("id")
strstatus = request.QueryString.Item("status")

If Len(strid) > 0 Then
    dtCurrentDate = Today
    strMessageName = "" & Hex(Year(dtCurrentDate)) & Hex(Month(dtCurrentDate)) & Hex(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Day(dtCurrentDate)) & CreateRandomGUID(13) & ""
    If Len(strstatus) > 1 Then
        SendAddr = "From: michael@bubble.com"
        RecAddr = "To: *STATUS." & strid & "@blah.co.nz"
        OutputString = SendAddr & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & RecAddr & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & strstatus & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & ""

        FileObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        strTempFile = MsgFilePath & "\" & strMessageName & ".tmp"

        OutStream = FileObject.CreateTextFile(strTempFile, True, False)
        OutStream.WriteLine(OutputString)
        OutStream.Close
        OutStream = Nothing

        MsgFile = FileObject.GetFile(strTempFile)
        MsgFile.Name = "BLAH" & strMessageName & ".EML"
    End If
End If 
%>
```

This routine worked perfectly well 99.9% of the time for years, however, every now and again, it inexplicably throws a 500 error as captured here from the http log

```
POST /BlahStat.aspx |128|800a0046|Permission_denied 443 - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1+(Java/1.8.0_161) - blah.site.net 500
POST /BlahStat.aspx |134|800a0035|File_not_found 443 - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1+(Java/1.8.0_131) - blah.site.net 500
POST /BlahStat.aspx |134|800a003a|File_already_exists 443 - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1+(Java/1.8.0_131) -blah.site.net 500
```

Actually, "File_already_exists" hasn't been seen for months since putting in the rename lines, which were added because the next service was attempting to lock and process the file before the write was finished. Bang! "Permission_denied" is/was the most frequent, although now a custom error page is implemented none of these errors get logged anymore, just the re-direct.

I appreciate there could be all sorts of reasons why such a routine could bomb out file writing on an Azure Web App (memory, outage etc), hence my question;

Is there anything **wrong** with this .aspx code that prevents it **always** functioning correctly..?

Comment: random question:  Is there some reason you are not using System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName here?

Comment: Suggest you avoid Scripting.FileSystemObject and use System.IO and specify sharing options that include Delete.

Comment: Just felt I wanted a bit more control over the file name, particularly in terms of uniqueness as routine can be called 1000s of times in a few seconds, which is when it starts crapping out... maybe asking too much of FileSystemObject, should do a proper API... need someone to fund it :o)

Comment: Getting 1000s of requests per second might stress the IO just a bit too much. Since you're hosting this in Azure, why not store it in [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/)? It's also more robust since you won't lose any files if the website gets a new instance.

Comment: You're absolutely right @rickvdbosch If I had my time all over again I'd use an API and Queues. Currently stuck with existing ported application, which was working fine until the load came on... just wondering if it can be improved.

Comment: Connection a storage account and writing this file to Blob storage instead of disk is less than an hour of work. Should be doable, right? Or put it up on GitHub so people can help you. 

Comment: Cheers @rickvdbosch the body of api/queues work is already in hand, just don't want the above to totally melt down before it's ready (it's a bit more than 1hr in the backend)